# Another UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I stumbled upon a situation that shutters my understanding of Pythons variable scope.

Here is the code:

```
transaction_id = None


def parseFileContent(hostID,marketID, content, writeToDB=False):
    features = _buildObjects(StringIO.StringIO(content))

    for feature in features:
        featureID =  adapter.addFeature(feature.name,boris)
        print transaction_id #breaks here UnboundLocalError: local variable 'transaction_id' referenced before assignment

        transaction_id = adapter.addFeatureTransactionToQueue(featureID, result[0], result[1], Command.ADD, boris, trans_id = transaction_id)
```

If I replace last line with

```
       adapter.addFeatureTransactionToQueue(featureID, result[0], result[1], Command.ADD, boris, trans_id = transaction_id)
```

Everything works. I need to understand what python dislikes about me printing the value in the first scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python compiler marks a name as local to a function *if you assign to it*. Your last line assigns to `transaction_id` so it is seen as a local name, not a global.

You need to tell the compiler *explicitly* that `transaction_id` is a global, by using the `global` keyword inside the function:

```
def parseFileContent(hostID,marketID, content, writeToDB=False):
    global transaction_id
```

If there is no assignment, a name is considered non-local instead and you do not need to mark it.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python doesn't have variable declarations, it needs another way to tell what's local to what scope. It does so by defining that anything a function assigns to is local to that function unless overridden by a `global` declaration. Thus, assigning to `transaction_id` makes it a local, and the `print` tries to print the unassigned local and fails.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to a name inside a function, it's a local name. Python will only ever treat the name as local inside that function, even if you have a global variable with the same name. This is different from some other languages, where if a local is not found, a global with the same name will be used if it exists.

You should avoid global variables. There is no reason for your `transaction_id` to be global in this case. So just put the `None` assignment *inside the function.* If you want access to the last transaction ID after the function executes, simply return it from the function.

```
def parseFileContent(hostID,marketID, content, writeToDB=False):
    features = _buildObjects(StringIO.StringIO(content))
    transaction_id = None     # <----------------------

    for feature in features:
        featureID =  adapter.addFeature(feature.name,boris)
        print transaction_id  # now works

        transaction_id = adapter.addFeatureTransactionToQueue(featureID, 
            result[0], result[1], Command.ADD, boris, trans_id=transaction_id)

     return transaction_id    # <----------------------
```

Comment: I don't use global variables, I was just puzzled by this scope phenomena. I had to cook this example to make my question as concise as possible.